# selenium chromedriver NoSuchElementException for windows while works fine on mac

Tags: java, scala, selenium

trying to operate a simple selenium task which filling a text field wuth some string and it works well on mac but not on windows...both works with chromdriver for selenium and I downloaded the same version of chromdriver...what could I have done wrong..? this is my error on windows...it just cant find this element...and if I inspect the page you can see that the element `id: name_of_user` does exist, dont know why it dosent recognise him..

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"name_of_user"}
  (Session info: chrome=62.5.3789.192)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161
(245ih23i5o24j5njnfvjndvvggbgbgbgbg
73),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provid
e any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 65 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/
no_such_element.html
arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.35.52
8161
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=name_of_user}
```

Comment: Have you tried waiting until the element is visible? I have often received this error because the page was still loading.

Comment: @AnthonyOkoth The problem was that I had to downgrade the selenium chromedriver...I still dont know why but the latest driver didnt work on my windows, and when downgraded it worked.

Comment: Is your Chrome browser up to date? I'm using the most up-to-date driver and browser and have no issues.